# Pic mixed with grey and RGB components in Python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to enhance one colour (e.g. 'Red') and other colour become greyscale(e.g. 'Blue & Green') therefore, the output figure is expected with 'RGB' mode and 'L' mode in Python PIL lib.

```
import PIL.Image as pim
file=input('Enter name of image to highlight: ')
colour=input('Enter colour to highlight: ')
multiplier=input('Enter multiplier: ')
m=float(multiplier)
original = pim.open(file)
highlight = pim.new("RGB", original.size)

highlight=original.convert('L')
#convert whole figure into greyscale

def high_red(r,g,b,m,x,y):
    if r>max(m*g,m*b):
        boosted_r=2*r-r**2/255
        reduced_g=g**2/255
        reduced_b=b**2/255
        colour=(int(boosted_r),int(reduced_g),int(reduced_b))
        highlight.putpixel((x, y), colour)
for x in range(original.width):
    for y in range(original.height):
        (r, g, b) = original.getpixel((x, y))
        if colour == 'Red':
            high_red(r,g,b,m,x,y)
```

However, the output is greyscale only without Red parts. I've also tried putpixel one-by-one which greyed part is written as

```
colour=round(0.2126*r+0.7152*g+0.0722*b)
highlight.putpixel((x, y), colour)
```

It still failed and only Red displayed. Did i define something wrong or should i have to generate 2 figures(RGB & grey) and paste into one?

Comment: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert you likely lost color information when converting to greyscale with `'L'`